# Why do 1/0 and Sqr (-1) throw error in MSOffice VBA, but not in VB.NET?

Tags: vba, vb.net

In MSOffice VBA, `1 / 0` throws error 11, and `Sqr (-1)` throws error 5. But in VB.NET, `1 / 0` does not throw an error, whose result is "∞". `Math.Sqrt (-1)` does not throw error either, whose result is "NaN". Why does it happen?

Answer (score 3):

Because the spec says so.

Both .NET's `Double` and VBA's `Double` are IEEE floating point values supporting the special values

- positive infinity,
- negative infinity, and
- NaN ("not a number").

However, in VBA, `1 / 0` is defined in the [VBA spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/d5418146-0bd2-45eb-9c7a-fd9502722c74) to

- not only set the result to `NaN`, but
- also to raise an error:

> If this results in dividing a nonzero value by 0, runtime error 11 (Division
> by zero) is raised.
>
> [...]
>
> In either of these cases, if this expression was within the right-hand side of
> a Let assignment and both operands have a declared type of Double, the
> resulting IEEE 754 Double special value (such as positive/negative infinity
> or NaN) is assigned before raising the runtime error.

Thus, you can initialize a VBA `Double` to positive infinity as follows:

```
Dim d As Double

On Error Resume Next
d = 1 / 0
On Error GoTo 0

Debug.Print d   ' yields " inf"
```

Comment: Note that in the .NET debugger, you can set it to break on floating point exceptions, though that may also require changing the floating point control settings so that the FP exception is raised (not sure offhand if .NET provides direct access to this).